# How can I make the thumbnails in a window xp appear to bigger in size?

Tags: windows-xp, images, thumbnails

How can I make the thumbnails in a window xp to appear bigger in size?

I am a designer, it would be best to quick glances over a bigger thumbnails, as what windows xp default thumbnail size is.

Answer (score 1):

For Xp use the program TweakUI as supplied by MS http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-xp  It had the feature of adjusting the thumb sizes.